# How to hide a button after clicking it in the MVC View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my MVC View. I want to **hide the button** with **id=btn** *(button is defined at the bottom most div of the code)* that shows the value of a particular table after I click it. Any idea how to achieve that? This button serves no purpose after it does its intended function.

```
@model IEnumerable<MovingApplication.Models.Class1>

@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.message = "hello world";
}

<div class="jumbotron" style="background:#E74C3C !important" >
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Table Data</h2>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!----------------------------Table 1 Defined--------------------------------->
<div id="table2">
    <table id="tableA" border="1" align="center"
           class="table tableA table-bordered table-hover 
           table-condensed table-layout: fixed text-center">
        <tr><td><b>Table 1</b></td></tr>
         @{
              foreach (var item in ViewBag.userdetails)
              {
                  <tr><td width="10%">@item.name</td></tr>
              }
          }
    </table>
</div>
<div id="table3">
</div>

<!------------Autocomplete Text Sent to MoveData Method------------------->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/MoveData",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { a: $("#name").val() },
            success: function (data) {
             $("#table3").html(data);
            }

        });

    }
</script>

<!---------------Code to show contents of Table 2----------------------->


<script type="text/javascript">
    function def()
    {

        $.ajax
            ({
            url: "/Home/ShowData",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { a: $("#name").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#table3").html(data);
             }
            });
    }
    </script>


<!-----------------Code to load autocomplete list-------------------------->



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Index",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>

<!----------------------------Input Field--------------------------------->

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="button1">
        <hr />
        <div >
            <div class="text-center" >
                <p><b>Enter Any Data</b></p>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    @Html.Editor("name", new { 
                    htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control text-mywidth" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"><br />
                <input type="button" style="grid-row-align:start;" 
                value="Move/Add" onclick="abc();" class="btn btn-success" />

                <input type="button" style="align-self:auto;"
                value="Show Table 2" id="btn" onclick="def();" class="btn btn-info" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    /*---------------Buttons defined to Add/Move/Show data-------------------*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You add `$("#btn").hide();` into `def` function.

```
function def()
    {
        $("#btn").hide();
        $.ajax
            ({
            url: "/Home/ShowData",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { a: $("#name").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#table3").html(data);
             }
            });
    }
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: If it is helpful, you don't forget award.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer since I don't have any reputation points.

Comment: Can you check best answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
```

to the onClick event on the button.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've already defined a `function` for `onclick` event of button. So you can just have `$("#btn").hide()` within it as below:

```
function def(){
     //Earlier code if any
     $("#btn").hide();    
}
```

As another option, you can add `click event` to your button as,

```
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
     //Show table 2
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: The first one works really well. The second one works only when I click it the second time.